# Speed up REST SOQL Query

Tags: soql, rest-api

Other than reducing the complexity of the Query is there any way of speeding up how quickly you can iterate through a SOQL Rest Query? I can't use bulk SOQL as I require Parent-to-child relationships in my query so that's a no go and there are a fair few hundred thousand records to go through at least. At the moment, it takes approximately 2-3 minutes to process this as it stands by just using the next URL but I can't know that next URL until I've had the previous result.

Answer (score 2):

Few ways to speed up querying lots of records in batch api.

- **Split the SOQL into batches**

  If the predicate of your SOQL is temporal and if you know the range, you can split the range into multiple ranges, query them in parallel and merge the results after the fact. This would result in involved merge process if you need dataset needed to be ordered.
- **Parallel next batch fetching**

  Note: this is not a supported method and could break in subsequent releases.
  When Salesforce returns `nextRecordUrl` it consists of two parts `<cursor id>-<startNum>`. For ex., `01gp000000AJ51VAAT-800`. You take the `totalSize` from your first query response, construct multiple urls and fire them in parallel. You need to ensure that batchSize used to calculate subsequent urls is same as batch returned in first query result.
- **Fetch less number of fields**

  Salesforce reduces the batch size if you have lots of fields in soql. If you have any not-required fields, remove them.
- **Ids SOQL and details SOQL**

  If you have lots of fields and you need to fetch all of those details, you can first fetch just ids and run multiple other detailed SOQLs for few ids (like 100 or so) and run them in parallel.

There is no free lunch with Salesforce. It will bite back one way or other. You just need to decide which limit to forgo when you try to optimize one. Some limits you may encounter.

- **Daily APIs limit**

  Each api calls adds to daily limit. If you are running short, multiple SOQLs may be aproblem.
- **Per user query cursor limit**

  Each user can have max 5 query cursors open. If you try to open too many, earlier query cursor will get closed and if you try to fetch using that you will get `INVALID_QUERY_LOCATOR` error.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to utilize built-in compression modules. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_rest_compression.htm